# Best method to Batch Update existing DynamoDb items using DynamoDb mapper

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-mapper

I am trying to find the best way to batch update items in a DynamoDb table using Java’s Dynamo db mapper. Is `DynamoDBSaveExpression` the right way to do it? Can I use DynamoDBSaveExpression to batch update (`batchSave()`) items based on a condition or does it only work with `save()` ? I do not see any examples that using `batchSave()` with `DynamoDBSaveExpression` in the documentation.

For example, I have a list of employees with different roles (Engineering, Marketing, etc) under a column called `role`. I want to update another column assume their `level` based on their `role` value.

One way is to query a list and filter based on the role (or query it efficiently using GSI), update those records and then `batchSave()` them back to the database. But I am trying to find the best way to batch update them directly without having to query them using DynamoDb mapper.

I have looked at the existing questions online and have not been able to get a clear answer, and want to avoid using an out dated method. Thank you!